# How to get a uniformly-distributed random integer-points in an nD ball?

Tags: python, numpy

[How to generate uniform random points inside d-dimension ball / sphere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544971/how-to-generate-uniform-random-points-inside-d-dimension-ball-sphere)

In this thread, @Thomas Lux has a wonderful solution of generating uniformly random points inside an nD ball with radius r=1. But now I want to generate points where their **Cartesian coordinates are integers**. I do not know any way except generating random points in a cube and **throwing out the points with norm greater than 1**.

I don't know if simply using `randint` or pushing `np.floor()` to the vector will do.

Comment: The naive `randint` solution should work but is very inefficient since an nD sphere volume is much slower than the one of its bounding-box when D is huge. The `np.floor` probably do not work since it should introduce a bias in the distribution (not fully random anymore unless you do some non-trivial correction). AFAIK, this is a quite complex problem to solve. Beside this, do you mean *Cartesian* coordinates?

Comment: The problem is, if I use randint to get the vector, after normalizing it would not be a interger-point

Comment: You can’t mean a norm of **1**…?

Comment: As David said, assuming you do not mean of norm 1 (since then then no integer points are in the n-sphere!) you need to simply figure out which integer points do land in the sphere and keep them in some list. Then you randomly output from that list which would give the desired result.

Comment: @SimonTartakovksy As said before, this naive method is really not efficient when `D` is big. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball for more information. In 2D, a disc takes 78% of the random 2D square space. In 3D, it is 51%. But in 15D, it is 0.001% which is very small. This means 99_999 integers over 100_000 will be filtered out. In fact the number of required tested points grows exponentially with `D`. With `D>40` this methods completely fail to even find only 1 point in the hyper-sphere in a reasonable time (ie. at least few weeks).

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `round()` on uniform real samples would almost work. Except the integer points near the edge of the ball would have lower probabilities of showing up. That's because the hypercube-neighborhood of a point on the edge is less than half-contained in the ball you're sampling from.

There is an easy workaround though. Generate real samples in a ball that fully contains all such hypercubes, the radius `r+sqrt(n)/2` should be enough for that, then apply rounding, and finally discard the integer points that are not within distance `r`.

Certainly the outer ball can be much larger than the inner one, depending on `r` and `n`, but the discard rate should still be better.

Comment: 1. do you have a proof that this statistically work? 2. the main issue is that the outer ball should be exponentially bigger as `n` grows. This means most try will fail (see my comment above). I guess this should be a bit better than the naive probing in a hypercube is the radius of the sphere is big. In fact, the probability to find a point in a `D`-hyper-sphere of radius `r` is `(r/(r+1))**D`. This means that this solution is good as long as `r` is not small and `D` is not huge. For example, with `r=5` and `D=15`, 6% of the points will be in the inner hyper-sphere. With `D=40`, 0.07%.

Comment: @JérômeRichard 1. if hypercube-neighborhoods around each valid integer point are non-overlapping, of equal volume and fully contained in the outer ball, then a sample taken uniformly from the outer ball is surely equally likely to hit any of them.
2. Ultimately, the cases with `r=100, n=10` and `r=10, n=100` will probably need different algorithms. No idea which case OP needs.

Comment: The uniformity look indeed Ok as long as value like 0.5 are randomly rounded to one of the nearest integer. Alternatively, an epsilon can be added to fix this tiny bias with a rounding to zero. It looks like the OP is unfortunately long gone... For the probability, I made a mistake. It is: `(r/(r+D**0.5/2))**D`. So the previous examples gives 0.7% and 0.0000003%. `D` should be small. Your solution is good when `r > O(D**1.5)`. The problem is very hard to solve when `r` is quite small and `D` is big (it looks like non-linear integer optimization). Interesting solution anyway.

Comment: @JérômeRichard if `r` is tiny and `D` is huge, then the integer coordinates are almost all 0, and there are just a few families of similar points permuted in many ways. e.g. if `r=3`, then all integer points in the ball are either 3,0... or 2,2,1,0... or 2,1,1,1,1,1,0... or 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0... or any of their subsets, or the same but with some minus signs. It's not a huge number of families, it's easy to see how big each of them is, easy to sample from.